# Multicolored line through css

Tags: css

[image]

```
<div class="border"></div>

.border {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727 20%, #1a82f7 80%);
}
```

The above code produces the line but its fading out the first color than fading in the other one. But i want line like the above one. So help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.border {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727 20%, #1a82f7 20%);
}
```

Trick is to start the second color right where first color ends. In this example `#2F2727` color is ending at 20% and `#1a82f7` color is starting from 20%.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create two separate DOM elements in order to have achieve the multi coloured line. Please see below:

HTML:

```
<div class="border">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border {
    height:6px
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.border div {
    height:6px;
}
.border div:first-child {
    width:30%;
    background-color:orange;
    float:left;
}
.border div:last-child {
    width:70%;
    background-color:black;
    float:left
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/NvQ7B/2/

Answer (score 1):

could you not just do something like this:

```
.border {
    height:3px;
    border-left:200px solid #2F2727;
    background-color:#1a82f7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff0000+0,ff0000+30,0a0e0a+30,0a0809+100;Custom

```
background: #ff0000; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 30%, #0a0e0a 30%, #0a0809 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(30%,#ff0000), color-stop(30%,#0a0e0a), color-stop(100%,#0a0809)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 30%,#0a0e0a 30%,#0a0809 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 30%,#0a0e0a 30%,#0a0809 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 30%,#0a0e0a 30%,#0a0809 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 30%,#0a0e0a 30%,#0a0809 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#0a0809',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```